# TFS list of inactive projects

Tags: tfs

I have TFS server with a bunch of projects and I need to know which projects are actively being used so I can remove the projects that are no longer under development.

I want to use the TFS2018 api to do this.

1. What would be the best way to get a list of projects that have been actively worked on for the past year?
2. What would be the best way to get a list of projects that have been built in the past year?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally we cannot achieve that directly with API, because there isn't an explicit state of the project to identify if the project is active or inactive. We can see the sate of the projects are all "`wellFormed`". See [Get a list of team projects](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfs/projects#by-state)

However you can try the API with the Workitems. Basically if all the related work items are **done** then the project should be inactive.

Reference below PS script sample which using the [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql#get-work-items) to retrieve the projects with the count of the **Done** work items. (**0** means **inactive**)

```
Param(
   [string]$collectionurl = "http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection",
   [string]$keepForever = "true",
   [string]$user = "username",
   [string]$token = "password"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$projecturi = "$($collectionurl)/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0"
$projects = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projecturi -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential).value.name


foreach ($project in $projects)

{

    function CreateJsonBody
  {

    $value = @"
    {
      "query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [State] <> 'Done' AND [System.TeamProject]='$project' AND [System.ChangedDate] < '2018-01-01' AND [System.ChangedDate] > '2017-01-01' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"
    }
"@

   return $value
  }

$json = CreateJsonBody

$uri = "$($collectionurl)/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

write-host "ProjectName:" $project : $result.workItems.Count
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andy, is it possible to get a list of projects ordered by the last checked in item timestamp? This way I could see what projects have been worked on in the past year.

Comment: @doorman No, the changeset (check in) is in collection level, generally we cannot retrieve the `project name` from the changeset unless you enabled the `check-in notes` policy and enter the `project name` as check-in note when you check in each change, thus we can retrieve the `project name` from the notes. See the REST API with [Get list of changesets](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/tfvc/changesets#get-list-of-changesets)